# Gatsby category slugs not working from dynamic category page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, slug

In my `gatsby-node.js` I create dynamic Category pages:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions: { createPage } }) => {
  const {
    data: { projects, categories },
  } = await graphql(`
    query Projects {
      projects: allGraphCmsProject(filter: { stage: { eq: PUBLISHED } }) {
        nodes {
          id
          slug
        }
      }
      categories: allGraphCmsCategory {
        nodes {
          id
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  projects.nodes.forEach(({ id, slug }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `${slug}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/ProjectPage.tsx'),
      context: { id, slug },
    });
  });

  categories.nodes.forEach(({ id, slug }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/category/${slug}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/CategoryPage.tsx'),
      context: { id },
    });
  });
};
```

Inside `src/templates/CategoryPage.tsx` I render a `CategoryList.tsx` component.

In the browser on the page `/category` (src/pages/category.tsx), I render also the list categories (`CategoryList.tsx` component). When I click a category from this page it's working fine and it shows a url like `/category/category-one` and shows the categorie page in the browser.

But then if I click another category (from within a category page (`src/templates/CategoryPage.tsx`), I get an url like `/category/category-one/category-two`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But then if I click another category (from within a category page
> (`src/templates/CategoryPage.tsx`), I get an url like
> `/category/category-one/category-two`?

Your page generation looks good, except some unnecessary template literals:

```
  projects.nodes.forEach(({ id, slug }) => {
    createPage({
      path: slug, // before was path: `${slug}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/ProjectPage.tsx'),
      context: { id, slug },
    });
  });
```

Your issue appears because you are missing an initial slash (`/`) at the beginning of the `to` `props` of the `<Link>` component.

On your category page:

```
<Link to={`/${slug}`}/>{categoryName}</Link>
```

*Note: I don't know your page structure but the goal is to add an initial slash.*

This is because `slug`, may come or not with an initial slash. If it doesn't, it will concatenate the current URL to the `slug` itself, like an anchor (`<a>`) normally does.